# How to best passively cool, spread heat from this 100w heat lamp?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

For example this https://www.amazon.ca/Infrared-Ceramic-Emitter-Reptile-Chicken/dp/B092QV54NM/
Would you use a 5 quart pot or a cpu cooler?

Comment: What would be the point of cooling it? What does "spread heat" mean? The intended purpose of that "lamp" is to [_radiate_ heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). It can't do that if it isn't hot. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to cool a given device is an engineering question, not a physics one.  "Best" is very dependent on constraints, e.g. size, cost, weight, etc. not to mention the specific design and purpose of the device itself.